# How to set set a new default download directory or folder after clicking a download button on a page. I am using cucumber with watir

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

How to set a new default download directory or folder after clicking a download button on a page. I am using cucumber with watir

Error message:

```
Then(/^the user clicks on "(.*)" download on "(.*)" page$/) do |field_name, page_name|
  # get the XPATH or CSS from page object file, Raises Error if not found
  begin
    selector, element_path = get_element_target(field_name, page_name).split('^^')
  rescue
    fail("Element Xpath is not found for #{field_name} in #{page_name} page objects File")
  end
  if selector.nil? || element_path.nil?
    fail("Element Xpath is not found for #{field_name} in #{page_name} page objects File")
  end
  selector = (selector.downcase.include? 'xpath') ? :xpath : :css

  # Create the Element object
  element_obj = @browser.element(selector, element_path)

  # Wait for element to be present
  wait_for_element(element_obj)

  # Focus on element to make it visible
  focus_on_element(element_obj)
  DOWNLOAD_DIR = "#{Dir.pwd}" + '/features/support/Downloads/'


  element_obj.click(DOWNLOAD_DIR)

  end
```

Comment: I would suggest handle this at the browser capability level. I can provide the answer but just want to know if you are using remote driver?

Comment: This might help: http://watir.com/guides/downloads.  But testing file download via webdriver isn't worth the effort IMO (e.g. fragile, webdriver is wrong tool for the job).  YMMV.